# How to make the heading hover in BOOTSTRAP 5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Kindly guide me how to make this heading hover in Bootstrap because I tried css but it isn't working. Thank you in advance.

> NOTE. Not included bootstrap links as I am using the downloaded
> compiled files.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap-Begining</title>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'>
   </head>
  <body>
    <!--TOP BAR THAT GONNA HOLD TITLE AND MENU-->
    <div id="top-bar"class="container-fluid"
    style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="title"class="col-6 p-5"style=" border: 1px solid white;">
        <p id="logo"style="color:white ;font-family: Lato;margin-left: 30%;">
        <span style="font-size:45px;">ENERGY FLASH.</span><br> /MUSIC BLOG</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what changes you want to achieve after hovering?

Comment: I want the font color change like green or purple and cursor to pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hovering on `#logo>span`which means direct child inside `#logo` of `type` `span` and changing the color of its text

```css
#logo>span:hover{
color:purple;
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap-Begining</title>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'>
   </head>
  <body>
    <!--TOP BAR THAT GONNA HOLD TITLE AND MENU-->
    <div id="top-bar"class="container-fluid"
    style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="title"class="col-6 p-5"style=" border: 1px solid white;">
        <p id="logo"style="color:white ;font-family: Lato;margin-left: 30%;">
        <span style="font-size:45px;">ENERGY FLASH.</span><br> /MUSIC BLOG</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to change the color of the text in the two span elements when hovering over them, you will need to use CSS as this cannot be achieved with just Bootstrap. To do this you need to select the div with the id="title" and its children. Your CSS might looks like this:

```
#title:hover span {
color: "yellow";
}
```

or

```
span:hover {
color: "yellow";
}
```

Also I recommend rearranging the elements in your #title  - they probably shouldn't all be wrapped in a p tag. Also look into Flexbox to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

You can look for information about the hover effects in the documentation
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/content-styles/hover-effects/#docsTabsOverview

Comment: yes, I have but I didn't get it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).